# Disable radio button with jQuery in dynamic form

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I've been driving myself nuts trying to get a radio button to be disabled in a form that is generated dynamically. This is the code that I am using. What is throwing an error is the ID name because of all the brackets in it. I tried escaping them but to no avail.

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("div.property_options_select input[id='#akID\\[114\\]\\[atRadioOptionID\\]\\[\\]1']").on('click',function(){
    $("input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
    });
});
```

The html:

```
<div class="property_options_select">

            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="akID[114][atRadioOptionID][]" id="akID[114][atRadioOptionID][]1" value="17"  class="ccm-input-radio"  />                  9:00AM - 11:00AM              </label>


            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="akID[114][atRadioOptionID][]" id="akID[114][atRadioOptionID][]2" value="18"  class="ccm-input-radio"  />                  9:30AM - 11:30AM              </label>
```

Anyone have a suggestion how to target that first radio button?

Comment: Why don't you refer the radio buttons  by there class name  `ccm-input-radio`. One more suggestion,try to avoid using attribute selector as its slower than class selector used directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the first child using the `:first-child`selector like this:

```
$("input:radio:first-child").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dajzvysg/

Comment: This assumes that it's only the first radio button that needs to be disabled. I understand from his script that it appears that is the case. But a better answer would help him understand how to access any of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You tried with double backslash?

```
$('#akID\\[114\\]\\[atRadioOptionID\\]\\[\\]1').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Sorry. When I posted the comment I missed the code button. I did have the double slashes in it. I think I found where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the double slash inside a jquery selector.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.property_options_select input[id='#akID\\[114\\]\\[atRadioOptionID\\]\\[\\]1']").on('click',function(){
            $("input:radio").attr('disabled',true); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the brackets. You just need to remove the `#`.

Your selector will be `$("div.property_options_select input[id='akID[114][atRadioOptionID][]1']")`

https://jsfiddle.net/3h4jpm1e/